# Format string without string.Format?

Tags: c#, string.format

I added a variable of type `int` and I used it to call something like:

```
x.ToString("0000");
```

I changed `x` to type `string` and now the above is invalid.  Is the only way to format `x` now:

```
string.Format("{0:0000}",x);
```

or is there a short-cut?

I am using `StringBuilder` to build the string, so does the same apply for `AppendFormat`?

Comment: Not really, this is basically the way to do it. You are formatting a string, no? Then why not use string.Format?

Comment: You have to [**parse**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) the string back to a number to be able to apply a new format. A number just has no format and a string is not numeric.

Comment: The result for `string.Format("{0:0000}",x)` is not the same for different kinds of x (namely `int` and `string`). So I guess you'll not get desired result by using the above expression.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - That is what I used to do, just not sure if there was a shorter way.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Convert objects to strings at the very last place where you want to display or print them, not earlier.

Comment: Why don't you just store it as "0000" initially?

Comment: I'd go with `PadLeft` or even better ... use a numeric type for a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real shortcut.

`Int32` doesn't have a concept of how many leading zeros the int should have.

You're doing the correct thing by formatting to string.  If you're using that to display stuff, it shouldn't really be an issue ( you still have `x` if you want to perform numeric operations ).

`AppendFormat` works like `string.Format`, but appends to the StringBuilder object it is called on.

Answer (score 3):

You can't format the string as you do a numeric value, so if you want to apply numeric formatting to the string you have to parse it to a number first:

```
Int32.Parse(x).ToString("0000")
```

Comment: @Xaisoft: Not so pointless, as at least it works... Using `string.Format("{0:0000}", x)` when `x` is a string is pointless, as the formatting is ignored. If `x` contains for example `"42"` you get the result `"42"`, not `"0042"`.

Comment: What I actually meant by pointless is that I would rather just do `string.Format` than convert it back to an `int` and then format it.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Yes, it's an inefficient and clumsy way to do it, but there is no shortcut as you have converted the value to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is the best way.  Remember that each type has its own ToString method that can be overridden.  The int type's ToString allows you to pass a format to format the integer when converted to string.  The DateTime is also similar.  However, a string type's ToString only returns the string because the source is already a string type.  To format a string, you must call string.Format.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have to convert the string representation of an integer to an actual integer so that it can be correctly formatted with the required number of leading zeros.

If the string is already in that format why do you need to reformat it?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN shows some ways using a specifier:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx#Y759

Example

```
x.ToString("G");
```

This link lists all the format options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: FYI, there are standard `.ToString()` for dates also.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.PadLeft(4, '0');
```

would provide the same result as

```
x.ToString("0000");
```

provided that `x` is still a number (it's a `string` so there's no way to be sure of that without at least `TryCast()`-ing it back.

Comment: PadLeft adds spaces I believe, so shouldn't you use: `x.PadLeft(4, '0')`?

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation (starting with C# 6).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

`{<interpolationExpression>[,<alignment>][:<formatString>]}`

With your example:

`$"{x:0000}"`